# how to sum total on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I wanna add items to total ( add prices ). So when I click (add to cart) it adds just number of items but I wanna add(sum) exactly prices.

```js
    class BookStore extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                total: 0,
                active: false, 

            }
            this.clicker = this.clicker.bind(this);

        }


    clicker() {
       let active = !this.state.active;
       this.setState({ 
           active: active, 
           total: this.state.total + 1

        })
    };


    render() {
        console.log(this.props.books);
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                <span className='mt-4'>Total: {this.state.total}</span>
                    {this.props.books.map((book, i)=> {

                        return (
                            <>

                            <div className='col-12 card book-card' key={i}>
                                <div className='row'>
                                    <div className='col-8'>
                                        <h5>{book.name}</h5>
                                        <h6>$ {book.price}</h6>
                                    </div>

                                <div className='col-4'>
                                    <button onClick={this.clicker} className=' btn btn-success' style={{width: '50%', }}>add to cart</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            </>
                        )
                    })}

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So how do I add that price to total that is related to according book. ( I mean, when I click on button I need to show total on {this state total} field

Comment: Use an Array.reduce function to calculate the total -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the question right but are you trying to pass the book price to the clicker function and add it to the total? If so, would something like this work for you?

```
// ...

clicker(price) {
       let active = !this.state.active;
       this.setState({ 
           active: active, 
           total: this.state.total + price

        })
    };

// ...

<button onClick={() => this.clicker(book.price)} className=' btn btn-success' style={{width: '50%', }}>add to cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question but here is a working React snippet with your code:

```js
class BookStore extends React.Component {
    state = {
        total: 0,
        active: false
    };


    clicker = (book) => () => {
       this.setState(state => ({ 
           active: !state.active, 
           total: state.total + book.price
       }));
    };


    render() {
      return (
          <div className='container'>
              <div className='row'>
              <span className='mt-4'>Total: {this.state.total}</span>
                  {this.props.books.map((book, i) => {
                      return (
                          <div className='col-12 card book-card' key={i}>
                              <div className='row'>
                                  <div className='col-8'>
                                      <h5>{book.name}</h5>
                                      <h6>$ {book.price}</h6>
                                  </div>

                                <div className='col-4'>
                                    <button onClick={this.clicker(book)} className=' btn btn-success' style={{width: '50%', }}>add to cart</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      )
                  })}
              </div>
          </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BookStore books={[{ name: "My Book", price: 20 }, { name: "My other Book", price: 50 }]} />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your onClick handler function  that is clicker send price as arguments.

`<button onClick={() => this.clicker(book.price)} className=' btn btn-success' style={{width: '50%', }}>add to cart</button>`

then you can access the books price in your clicker function.

```
clicker(price) {
   this.setState({ 
       active: !this.state.active, 
       total: this.state.total + price
    })
};
```

Comment: You need to use a double arrow function clicker: (price)=> ()=>{};

Comment: Do you know what that double arrow function means? have you tried using it?

Comment: okay now, see the difference between yours and mine.. `onClick={() => this.clicker(book.price)}` this is how i assign it to onClick.. and this is how you do.. `onClick={this.clicker(book)}` both are correct..  basically when you write two arrow function the first arrow function just returns the the second arrow function.. When onClick event triggers my code will call two functions yours will only call one function(the second one in two arrow function)..